# Need some help with json and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json, each

I cannot figure out json for whatever reason, i don't understand why i cannot get this to work.

my json is returning:

```
{"lists":[{"item":"1","count":"5"}]}
{"lists":[{"item":"1","count":"5"}]}
{"lists":[{"item":"1","count":"5"}]}
{"lists":[{"item":"1","count":"5"}]}
{"lists":[{"item":"1","count":"5"}]}
```

etc, etc, etc

now i am trying to retrieve it by using:

```
$.getJSON("lists.php",
  {id: aid},function(data){
  $.each(data.lists, function(i, info) {
      $('.container').append(info.item+info.count);
  });
});
```

but i don't get any data here. can anyone point me in the right direction?

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're used to how URL parameters are encoded. JSON works differently.

If you want your object to contain a key `lists` which contains an array, you should return JSON like this:

```
{
  "lists": [
    {"item":"1","count":"5"},
    {"item":"1","count":"5"},
    {"item":"1","count":"5"},
    {"item":"1","count":"5"},
    {"item":"1","count":"5"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: i am still having issues here, first, i dont know how to return the information like that in a php while loop, and second, i just tried that and i am still not getting any results, any ideas?

Comment: The simplest solution is to emit the prologue and epilogue before and after the loop.  However, you should consider emitting each record as a string, then using something like `join` to concatenate them separated by commas.  You can inject that result into the `lists` field.

Comment: As far as it not working, your JavaScript looks correct. You'll need to log some values to the console (try `console.log`) and update your question.

Comment: i can't get this to work still, i am having no luck. i am so frustrated.

Comment: You should log the values of `data`, `aid`, `info`, and perhaps even `$('.container')` to the console, and post them as an update to your question so that we have more information. :-)

Comment: i finally got it to work, it was an issue with the json still, but i got it to work with everyones help, thanks for all of the help i appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to return the data like this:

```
{
  "lists":[
    {"item":"1","count":"5"},
    {"item":"1","count":"5"},
    {"item":"1","count":"5"},
    {"item":"1","count":"5"},
    {"item":"1","count":"5"}
  ]
}
```

In your php, do the following:

```
echo "{\"lists\":[";
foreach ($lists as $obj) {
  echo "{\"item\": \"" . $obj->item . "\", ";
  echo "\"count\": \"" . $obj->count . "\"},";
}
echo "]}\n";
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i am still having issues here, first, i dont know how to return the information like that in a php while loop, and second, i just tried that and i am still not getting any results, any ideas?

Comment: @mcbeav , its a plain string , just make your response in that string format.

Answer (score 1):

The above isn't valid JSON.  I believe this is the syntax you are looking for, which would be described as "an object with a list property containing an array of items":

```
{"lists":[{"item":"1","count":"5"},{"item":"1","count":"5"},{"item":"1","count":"5",{"item":"1","count":"5"},{"lists":[{"item":"1","count":"5"}]}
```

You probably need to adjust your backend code so it's adding a new member to the "lists" array rather than an entirely new "lists" each time.

Comment: i am still having issues here, first, i dont know how to return the information like that in a php while loop, and second, i just tried that and i am still not getting any results, any ideas?

Comment: "lists" should be an array in PHP.  Push new item/count objects to it within the loop.